# Partial derivative $\frac{\partial u(x_1, x_2)}{\partial x_1}$ with $u(x_1, x_2)=v(x_1) + x_2$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to find the partial derivate of a function of the following form:

$u(x_1, x_2)=v(x_1) + x_2$ where $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R_+}$ and $v:\mathbb{R_+} \mapsto \mathbb{R_+}$.

I'm looking for: $\frac{\partial u(x_1, x_2)}{\partial x_1}$.

I think this is actually pretty simple but I don't know if my assumption is correct: is this just a simply nested function so I can use the chain rule to determine the derivative?

E.g. $(u \circ v)'(x_0)=u'(v(x_0))*v'(x_0)$, and therefore $\frac{\partial u(x_1, x_2)}{\partial x_1}=v'((x_1)) * 1 = v'(x_1)$. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: No, in this case $u$ is not composed with $v$ but say you had $u(v(x_1), x_2)$, then you could use the chain rule.

Comment: Your final answer is correct, but I didn't quite get what you meant just before that. Partial derivative w.r.t $x_1$ simply means that you assume $x_2$ to be constant and differentiate given function as how you would take derivative of single variable function.